SwiftUI TextField and Button Overlap Issue with safeAreaInset(edge:.bottom)
Description:
I'm working on a SwiftUI layout where I have a TextField for amount input and a "Max" button positioned below the text field. I also have a "Submit" button that should float above the keyboard when the amount input field is active.
To achieve this, I used .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) for the "Submit" button, which successfully makes the button float above the keyboard. The amount input field and the "Max" button are no longer obscured by the keyboard.
However, the issue is that the "Max" button is not clickable when the keyboard is visible. It appears to be visually accessible but is unresponsive to taps.
Expected Behavior:
The "Max" button should be clickable even when the keyboard is displayed.
The "Submit" button should remain floating above the keyboard.
What I Tried:
I used .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) for the "Submit" button.
I ensured the VStack containing the input and "Max" button is not obscured by the keyboard.
Environment:
SwiftUI project targeting iOS 16
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amountText: String = ""
    @State private var balance: String = "100.00"
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 500)
                    
                    Text("Enter Amount")
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    TextField("Enter amount", text: $amountText)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Balance: \(balance)")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        
                        Button("Max") {
                            amountText = balance
                        }
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 70) {
                Button("Submit") {
                    print("Submitted with amount: \(amountText)")
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
    }
}

Question:
How can I adjust the layout so that the "Max" button remains clickable even when the keyboard is displayed, while keeping the "Submit" button floating above the keyboard?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Just ran your code on Xcode 16, and it's working as expected. I was able to click max button, the textfield populated with 100.00 and also was able to click submit button.
